# yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb and yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores in CapacityScheduler

Tags: hadoop, scheduler, hadoop-yarn

There is one thing about Hadoop's Capacity Scheduler, which confuses me.

From Hadoop source code, I found out that `yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb` and `yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores` configurations cannot be 0 for   `CapacityScheduler` to work.

```
private void validateConf(Configuration conf) {
// validate scheduler memory allocation setting
int minMem = conf.getInt(
  YarnConfiguration.RM_SCHEDULER_MINIMUM_ALLOCATION_MB,
  YarnConfiguration.DEFAULT_RM_SCHEDULER_MINIMUM_ALLOCATION_MB);
int maxMem = conf.getInt(
  YarnConfiguration.RM_SCHEDULER_MAXIMUM_ALLOCATION_MB,
  YarnConfiguration.DEFAULT_RM_SCHEDULER_MAXIMUM_ALLOCATION_MB);

if (minMem <= 0 || minMem > maxMem) {
  throw new YarnRuntimeException("Invalid resource scheduler memory"
    + " allocation configuration"
    + ", " + YarnConfiguration.RM_SCHEDULER_MINIMUM_ALLOCATION_MB
    + "=" + minMem
    + ", " + YarnConfiguration.RM_SCHEDULER_MAXIMUM_ALLOCATION_MB
    + "=" + maxMem + ", min and max should be greater than 0"
    + ", max should be no smaller than min.");
}

// validate scheduler vcores allocation setting
int minVcores = conf.getInt(
  YarnConfiguration.RM_SCHEDULER_MINIMUM_ALLOCATION_VCORES,
  YarnConfiguration.DEFAULT_RM_SCHEDULER_MINIMUM_ALLOCATION_VCORES);
int maxVcores = conf.getInt(
  YarnConfiguration.RM_SCHEDULER_MAXIMUM_ALLOCATION_VCORES,
  YarnConfiguration.DEFAULT_RM_SCHEDULER_MAXIMUM_ALLOCATION_VCORES);

if (minVcores <= 0 || minVcores > maxVcores) {
  throw new YarnRuntimeException("Invalid resource scheduler vcores"
    + " allocation configuration"
    + ", " + YarnConfiguration.RM_SCHEDULER_MINIMUM_ALLOCATION_VCORES
    + "=" + minVcores
    + ", " + YarnConfiguration.RM_SCHEDULER_MAXIMUM_ALLOCATION_VCORES
    + "=" + maxVcores + ", min and max should be greater than 0"
    + ", max should be no smaller than min.");
}
```

But in `FairScheduler` they can be 0.

```
private void validateConf(Configuration conf) {
// validate scheduler memory allocation setting
int minMem = conf.getInt(
  YarnConfiguration.RM_SCHEDULER_MINIMUM_ALLOCATION_MB,
  YarnConfiguration.DEFAULT_RM_SCHEDULER_MINIMUM_ALLOCATION_MB);
int maxMem = conf.getInt(
  YarnConfiguration.RM_SCHEDULER_MAXIMUM_ALLOCATION_MB,
  YarnConfiguration.DEFAULT_RM_SCHEDULER_MAXIMUM_ALLOCATION_MB);

if (minMem < 0 || minMem > maxMem) {
  throw new YarnRuntimeException("Invalid resource scheduler memory"
    + " allocation configuration"
    + ", " + YarnConfiguration.RM_SCHEDULER_MINIMUM_ALLOCATION_MB
    + "=" + minMem
    + ", " + YarnConfiguration.RM_SCHEDULER_MAXIMUM_ALLOCATION_MB
    + "=" + maxMem + ", min should equal greater than 0"
    + ", max should be no smaller than min.");
}

// validate scheduler vcores allocation setting
int minVcores = conf.getInt(
  YarnConfiguration.RM_SCHEDULER_MINIMUM_ALLOCATION_VCORES,
  YarnConfiguration.DEFAULT_RM_SCHEDULER_MINIMUM_ALLOCATION_VCORES);
int maxVcores = conf.getInt(
  YarnConfiguration.RM_SCHEDULER_MAXIMUM_ALLOCATION_VCORES,
  YarnConfiguration.DEFAULT_RM_SCHEDULER_MAXIMUM_ALLOCATION_VCORES);

if (minVcores < 0 || minVcores > maxVcores) {
  throw new YarnRuntimeException("Invalid resource scheduler vcores"
    + " allocation configuration"
    + ", " + YarnConfiguration.RM_SCHEDULER_MINIMUM_ALLOCATION_VCORES
    + "=" + minVcores
    + ", " + YarnConfiguration.RM_SCHEDULER_MAXIMUM_ALLOCATION_VCORES
    + "=" + maxVcores + ", min should equal greater than 0"
    + ", max should be no smaller than min.");
}
```